# woocommerce HTML blocks comments for wordpress 5.9 and block based theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have a block based theme and i installed woocommerce on it, then i created single-product.html inside my block-templates folder. now i want to display all i want and need: like product-title,price and so on. but the html comment i use doesn't show the values.

```
<!-- woocommerce:product-price /-->
```

i have spent 3 hours searching in woocommerce documentations for the appropriate html comments, and found nothing.

what am i missing? where can i find a list of all their comments blocks so i can create templates for them?

this is wordpress 5.9, meaning with full site editing

best regards

Comment: Were you able to find some solution for this? I used the legacy template option for woocommerce instead of trying to create a block.. so it displays the legacy view which can still be controlled and modified using `remove_action()` etc.. but I am still unable to add a sidebar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71259221/how-to-get-sidebar-in-a-block-based-theme-can-we-use-html-and-php-files-togethe)

Comment: `<!-- wp:woocommerce/legacy-template {"template":"single-product"} /-->` .. this is what I used.. hope it helps

Comment: hi, thanks for your comments. but what i want is the freedom to make a template ( block based theme) that i can put each element inside my custom layout. so for example: just the product price, or product ratings....and so on. by the way, where did you got this comment of the legacy-template?

Comment: As of now, even I am waiting to have that option of being able to have each attribute for woocommerce placed/designed.. but I think (I could be wrong) the feature is still not out there without using php.. regarding the line of code that got me the legacy template, it gets added when you create a block template in full site editor.. you will notice it when you export the files and then you have to replace that template or template part in your theme files..