# How to get sidebar in a Block Based Theme? Can we use html and php files together for templates?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, sidebar

The requirement before full site editing to display your sidebar was of 2 steps

1. 'register the sidebar' in functions.php and
2. 'call the sidebar' in your template php file using `dynamic_sidebar()`

Now with Block Based Themes and Full Site Editing, I am able to register the file as the functions.php is still a php file..

**But as for the templates we don't use any php file, how exactly do we call the sidebar to appear on the page?**

I've been struggling with trying to make a sidebar for woocommerce visible on a block based theme for over 2 days now and would appreciate some guidance on this.

**UPDATED on 21-03-2022**

(Originally posted on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-woocommerce-ready-for-full-site-editing/)

I am experimenting with Full Site Editing and would like to move to Blocks completely and wanted to know if this is possible with the current woocommerce plugin.

Recently I tried to create a theme/template and to use woocommerce I had to use this line in the template for archive-product

```
<!-- wp:woocommerce/legacy-template {"template":"archive-product"} /-->
```

So it seems that one still needs to use the legacy template.. Now when I use the block filters on a sidebar and the legacy template on the main area, the filters don’t work.

So my question is

**1) Can I use Full Site Editing for a woocommerce template?**

If no, then we don’t need to go ahead… but if yes, then please help me understand how?

If I create the filter on the sidebar using blocks and the products on the main then the whole thing seems to work.. so that’s basically me creating a PAGE and not using /shop or /category

But if i try to use the /shop template then I think the old legacy template gets loaded.. and from my limited knowledge, it seems the get_sidebar() does not work anymore with FSE (I could be wrong) and so how do I add filters?

Here’s a link to the view I have on a test site..

https://wordpress.alimbolar.com/eyeglasses-store-eyeglasses-category/

Now this is a Products By Category Block on the main area and the Products By Attribute Filters on the left sidebar.. as you can see there are only 2 products on the right but the filter on the left is showing 6 as the total so something’s not right..

Then here’s the default Shop page that’s pointing to a blank PAGE named Shop

https://wordpress.alimbolar.com/shop/

And here I have the products and I have no clue on how to add filters as the get_sidebar() option I assume requires PHP and in FSE templates I have no idea how to get this to work.. so any advise would be appreciated.

As would be obvious I am new to WordPress but I am excited with Blocks and find that a lot can be done with it for plain WordPress but I’d like to do more with WooCommerce.. Any guidance, links to resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Like you have discovered, block themes does not use widgets and widget areas.

The reasoning behind this is that users don't need widget areas when they can place blocks anywhere on any part of the website.

If these widgets are essential and there are no block alternatives, then I would recommend to not switch to full site editing *yet*.

If you meant to add a design with a sidebar containing blocks, not widgets, then there are several ways to do this.

- Create a custom page template (from the block editor Template section, not the Site Editor).
- Add a columns block. Place the blocks that you want to display in the
  sidebar in the narrow column. -I recommend the [WooCommerce blocks
  plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/).
- Add your main content blocks to the wide column.
- Assign that page template to any post type where you want the sidebar to display.

Comment: Thanks for the update.. I've already attempted what you've advised but I was stuck and then approached wordpress support page for woocommerce and I have this post but stackoverflow for some reason doesn't allow me to share a link here in the comments.. so i'll add the post content to my question.. please let me know if you can help me..